# Development for Android & IOS

Tags: android, ios

I know that this question was asked quite a few times, but I could not find a satisfactory answer.  I would like to develop an app that would work on both iOS and Android.  Actually, I already have an Android version -- would like to port that under iOS and keep further development "parallel" while reusing as much of the code as possible.  I know there are tools slated for that; I'm currently looking at Xamarin and Visual Studio.

I would like to at least start without a Mac.  I know I won't be able to fully deploy onto an iPhone, let alone submit it to the App store.  Basically, all I am looking for at this point is a "Hello World" line on an iPad simulator/emulator on a Windows PC.  Once I get going with this, I will make a decision to obtain a Mac, get an iOS device, register, etc.

The main reason I don't want to just get a Mac (or Mac-in-the-cloud) is that I want to do most of the development during my commute, without a reliable Internet connection.  I want to develop on a Windows laptop; I don't want to carry 2 laptops.  I just want some sort of a way to compile and test the app until it is 90% ready.

Once again, I am looking for a way, under Windows, to compile my app and run some sort of an iOS emulator/simulator where the app can be "side-loaded" and executed.  Is there a way to do that?  Books/links?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to install Xcode and Mac OS X in VirtualBox on Windows,you can find many tutorials online, here is an one:
https://www.bluecloudsolutions.com/blog/develop-apps-on-windows-pc/

Comment: Nice link, thanks.  Will definitely try.

Comment: YES!  It took some time with looking around the Internet for the right files and manuals, but I've got a "Hello World" Xamarin project running on both Android and iOS simulator!

Comment: congrats! Xamarin is awesome.